# Javascript: Change <a href> to match <img src> multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, html, image, href, src

I'm attempting to write a script that will take the 'img src' and copy it to an 'a href'. The trick is that this page I'm working on is a photo gallery, with multiple images on the page that this script needs to work on. This needs to happen as soon as the page is loaded. Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- Album row 1 -->
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 album">
  <a class = "img-container-alt" href="**this_is_where_the_imgsrc_below/will_end_up.jpg**" data-gallery>
   <div class="photo-overlay"></div>
    <figure>
     <img class="img-responsive album-img" src="**this_is_what_/i_would_like_copied_above.jpg**" alt="">
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

The trick is, like I said, getting it to run through multiple divs that are identical to this one and dynamically grabbing each `img src` and copying it to the `a href` above it within the `div`. Here's what JS I've done so far:

```
    <!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function abc() {
    console.log('hello')
    var copyto = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container-alt');
    var copy = document.querySelectorAll('album-img');
    for (var i = 0; i < copyto.length; i++) {
        var url = copy[i].src;
        copyto[i].href = url;
    }
}
</script>
```

When I run that, I get this error:
        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined, which is referring to the `var url = copy[i].src;`. I'm not sure if my script is the best option for what I'm trying to do, but I'm stumped now. I'm relatively new to JS, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. If I need to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Ian Devlin and @t.niese, I had two problems that needed to be fixed. First, my `var url = copy[i].src;` was undefined. Why? Because I was missing a `.` in my `var copy = document.querySelectorAll('.album-img');` where `album-img` was. Secondly, I couldn't grab the `src` in the `var url = copy[i].src;`, so we switched that to `copy[i].getAttribute("src")` and it worked perfectly.

Here's the working script now....

```
    <!-- Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function abc() {

     var copyto = document.querySelectorAll('.img-container-alt');
     var copy = document.querySelectorAll('.album-img');
     for (var i = 0; i < copyto.length; i++) {

        var url = copy[i].getAttribute("src");
        copyto[i].href = url;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

[`getQuerySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `Nodelist` of [`element` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) so I suspect you need to use `.getAttribute("src")` instead.

Comment: So instead of `var copy = document.queryselectorall('album-img')`, you're proposing, `var copy = document.getAttribute("src")`, correct? It appears to not work this way since `.getAttribute` is not a function.

Comment: No, I mean try `copy[i].getAttribute("src")` in your loop. But what t.niese says below is also correct. Always debug your code and see where the value is null.

Comment: Your `copy[i].getAttribut("src")` was exactly what I needed. ALSO, @t.niese solved my other issue that I was having, (missing the '.' in my `album-img`... gosh.) The two of you both helped me and together your answers solved my problem. Thanks a ton guys. I'll be referencing this going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll('.album-img')` (you are missing a `.` in front of the `album-img`)  otherwise you search for the elements with the tag name `album-img`.

Your `document.querySelectorAll('album-img')` will return an empty node list because there is no element with the tag name `album-img` in your html code and because of that every access to `copy[i]` will return `undefined`.

But I would use another approach anyway. I would search for all images and then for each image check if it is inside of an `a` element and if this is the case then change the `href` of that element:

```
function find_closest_a(el) {
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName === 'A') return el;
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll('.album-img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var aElment = find_closest_a(images[i]);
  if (aElment) {
    aElment.href = images[i].src;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my missing `.`. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes..... Your suggestions and @Ian Devlin's together were what I needed. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @tman091 check the edit  (adding another approach) I made right at the moment when you wrote the comment

Comment: Very intriguing. I like that. Since what I need is working, and the page isn't going to be changing all that often, I'll stick with the original loop for now - but make no mistake, I'm bookmarking this page! haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a data attribute so you can target only the images involved in the process, therefore skipping anything like icons etc

So, your img tag would change to:

```
<img class="img-responsive album-img" src="" alt="" data-copy-target="id_of_relevant_a_tag">
```

then in your js:

```
(function () {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-copy-target]');
    for (var i = 0, len = imgs.length; i < len; ++i) {
        document.getElementById(imgs[i].dataset.copyTarget).href = imgs[i].src;
    }
})();
```

Stick the script at the bottom of your page (before the closing body tag) to ensure it's executed only when the rest of the DOM is loaded

I haven't properly tested the above code but the principle is sound

The method I've used for the JS is to wrap it in a self-executing closure

Comment: I will definitely reference this script in a different page on my site, because this makes it seem a lot easier than what I was doing before. Makes sense. Thanks for your time! However, the other answers solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. Although, I'd still suggest at least using a data-attribute and not rely on the query selector returning your images and links in the correct order. If there's dynamic content that could contain either links or images on your page, then your script could fail

Comment: Dully noted. I'll play around with that solution on another page I'll be working on later today, because that page is more dynamic as far as content goes than the one I'm currently working on. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Just holla if you're having any trouble with that other page and I'll happily lend a hand